# Set Facebook graph Request to always return English results

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

The language of the results returned depends on the settings on a users phone and/or their location. I want to force the request to only return English results. 
The request in question is just a simple "me" request for a user. 
So far I have tried to add "local" in the parameteres like this:

```
GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
        }
    });
    Bundle param = new Bundle();
    param.putString("fields", "albums, id, birthday, photos&locale=en_us");    
    graphRequest.setParameters(param);
    graphRequest.executeAsync();
```

I have also tried to do it like this:

```
String graphPath = "/me?fields=id,name , first_name,albums, last_name&locale=en_us";
    GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), graphPath, null, HttpMethod.GET, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            Log.i(TAG, "response: " + response);
            Log.i(TAG, "object: " + response.getJSONObject());
        }
    });
    GraphResponse response = request.executeAsync();
```

Both without any luck. Last method actually works in the Facebooks Graph Api Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dalbums%26locale%3Dnb_no&version=v2.5

Without adding the "&locale=en_us" the top graph request works as intended.

Comment: The locale parameter should be respected..  It works well whenever I've used it... Note that in your top example, the locale should be added separately as a second string parameter: as in `param.putString("fields", "albums, id, birthday, photos"); param.putString("locale", "en_us"); `

Comment: I have actually tried that too, but I still do not get only "en_us" results.

Comment: Which fields exactly are you expecting to be in English?  In your example, the only fields that Facebook will translate are the titles of the default albums (Mobile Uploads, etc.)

Comment: The album names, and the Gender field. (In this example i actually did not include gender as field).

Comment: @Slagathor have you found anything?

Comment: @MustafaGüven Check my answer below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was actually a bug in the Facebook sdk version I had, so it would not return only english results. It works to set "locale" as an extra parameter. The correct way to do it is:

```
GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
        }
    });
    Bundle param = new Bundle();
    param.putString("fields", "gender, email, name, albums");
    param.putString("locale", "en_US");
    graphRequest.setParameters(param);
    graphRequest.executeAsync();
```

If this does not work for you, try to upgrade your Facebook sdk. I'm now on version 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0' and this works perfectly.