# facebook login page labels are showing in hindi language but not in English

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am an android developer.

I am used facebook sdk, but  while configuring facebook account in Empathy, the labels are showing in hindi language but not in English. How to change this to English. 
I just need Facebook login page English

When the user Facebook login, I should see the Facebook login page labels are showing in English language[image]

Comment: Is your device language also set up as Hindi? It's probably because of that. Try changing the device language.

Comment: @Tharkius my device language set is english

Comment: @Tharkius  When I login to Facebook for any other application, than he is showing english there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Facebook graph Request to always return English results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372011/set-facebook-graph-request-to-always-return-english-results)

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem and that was caused because I am changing the configuration in one of my activity before AuthActivity and that change causes changing the facebook language into Spanish.

```
 public void setLocaleToEnglishOnly(Context context) {

    String languageToLoad = "es"; //changing it into 'en'solved my problem 
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```